# Does MAMP installation create conflicts with standalone MySql?

Tags: macos, mysql, mamp

I have just installed MAMP. And I have just now realized that I already have a MySQL server and a database that runs under it. Do I now have two MySQL servers? Will they interfere with each other (and if yes, what would I need to do to have the existing database to work with the MAMP version)?

Comment: Please don't crosspost!

Comment: This question does not appear to be about Apple hardware or software within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: This wasn't meant as a crosspost. I brought it here when it was declared offtopic at StackOverflow.

Comment: This wasn't meant as a crosspost. I brought it here when it was declared offtopic at StackOverflow.  I thought that it was appropriate for this group because of this statement in the description of appropriate topics:  >>third-party hardware, services and software when associated for use with Apple products.>>  Since the first 'M' in mamp stands for Macintosh, I thought of this as  third party software for Apple.

Comment: MAMP stands for Mac Apache MySQL PHP. it is Mac-specific third party software. How is that off-topic? Also MAMP lets you specify what ports it operates on and comes up, by default, on non-standard ports so it does not interfere with software that comes with the OS.

Comment: Uups, sorry, I picked the wrong "on hold" reason. Question edited and reopened. If necessary please ask a second question for the python issue.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't anticipate any problems.  I've seen those configurations work just fine.  The only concern I see is that the built in versions of the software get updated automatically by Apple, and the versions you installed will not.  However, Apples updates include the latest fixes more slowly, so if you are diligent in installing them, yours will be up to date a little sooner.  If you are not, the Apple versions are easier to keep updated as the updates are almost completely automatic.